# Rack: Bundler::GemNotFound errors during `bundle install --deployment`

Tags: sinatra, bundler, rack, passenger, puppet

So I have a few machines in production that are running a Sinatra app on top of Rack. Usually everything is hunky dory until Puppet - which we're using to sync changes to our servers - notices that the Gemfile.lock for the project has changed, and as a result, needs to issue the `bundle install --binstubs --deployment` command so we get the new gems. When this happens, ANY http request will cause a 500 error when it calls into Bundler to require our gems, because the new gems haven't been installed yet.

We usually have at least one Rack process hanging around due to another process that periodically makes an http request to ensure the server is alive, but when this happens, there are no Rack processes alive. It seems like the `PassengerMinInstances` directive might help if the problem were with new instances, but we also have a process that periodically fetches a page to test that the server is still up, so there still should be at least one Rack process alive to handle the request.

I should probably note that puppet doesn't actually restart Rack (by `touch`ing the restart.txt file) until after the `bundle install` has completed, so it doesn't make any sense why our Rack processes would go away at this time. Has anyone encountered anything like this? Is there some Rack option to not reload the entire environment on every request that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity's sake, I'll answer this question. As part of the deployment, all of the files were touched with chown -R, which updates the ctime (but not the mtime) of the file. There is also an interesting [bug/feature](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/df391fb2310d9440#) in Passenger where they will restart the server whenever the mtime or ctime of the /tmp/restart.txt file changes.

Solution: stop chowning the directory during a deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but what I've done in the past to get around this kind of thing happening is to deploy the app into version-numbered dirs with a soft link pointing to them and an (Nginx) proxy server routing requests to the link. At the end of the deployment the deploy script points the link to the new app.

It seemed to work well enough for me, and if things really go wrong you can always manually repoint the link back to the previous version.

Comment: Interesting. That's not a bad solution if you don't mind doing a full checkout of your application (and presumably dependent gems as well) each deploy. That's a lot of bandwidth though, if you deploy regularly...